# Is it possible to name a part of a command to reuse it in the same command later on?

Tags: bash, command-line, line-editor

If I want to move a file called `longfile` from `/longpath/` to `/longpath/morepath/` can I do something like

```
mv (/longpath)/(longfile) $1/morepath/$2
```

i.e. can I let the bash know that it should remember a specific part of the input so I can reuse it later in the same input? 
(In the above example I use an imaginary remembering command that works by enclosing in parantheses and an imaginary reuse command `$` that inserts the content of the groups)

Comment: Why not a variable then?

Comment: For example, the above fits in one line and doesn't leave two variables behind that are never used again. I am not sure if there are more advantages/applications, I was mostly curious

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You *could* do this:

```
mv /longpath/longfile !#:1:h/morepath/
```

See https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#History-Interaction

- `!#` is the current command
- `:1` is the first argument in this command
- `:h` is the "head" -- think `dirname`
- `/morepath/` appends that to the head
- and you're moving a file to a directory, so it keeps the same basename.

If you want to alter the "longfile" name, say add a ".txt" extension, you could

```
mv /longpath/longfile !#:1:h/morepath/!#:1:t.txt
```

Personally, I would cut and paste with my mouse. In practice I never get much more complicated than `!!` or `!$` or `!!:gs/foo/bar/`

Answer (score 15):

You could also do this with brace expansion:

```
mv /longpath/{,morepath/}longfile
```

The shell expands this so that the `mv` command sees it the same as:

```
mv /longpath/longfile /longpath/morepath/longfile
```

Answer (score 9):

If you are for more efficient typing in command line, you may find [various readline shortcut](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Readline-Killing-Commands.html) useful. Readline is already built-in your shell. For your paricular case you could yank/delete parts of your line and then recall them from readline killiring.

Moreover, if you have EDITOR environmnent variable set to your favorite editor, then Ctrl-X,Ctrl-E will copy your current command line into editor window where you can have all the editor power to modify your line. Once completed, you save/exit from the editor and the line gets executed in your shell.

Comment: After having spent weeks on learning vim, I was actually upset that I still had to hold the left-arrow in the console forever to move around in my commands. Now I can apply all my newly acquired vim magic for that. Wonderful!

Comment: @Bananach: you can also set bash to vi-mode: `set -o vi` in bashrc. Then pressing esc on the command line puts you in the equivalent of vim's normal mode.

Comment: @kundor, I use `set -o vi` myself, but it's not nearly as powerful as Vim's normal mode—it has a subset of the commands of POSIX vi.  Still very useful, though, and you can use `<Esc>v` to open the command for editing in Vim.

Answer (score 4):

For something like the specific case you are asking about, you can also use a subshell.

```
mv (/longpath)/(longfile) $1/morepath/$2
```

becomes

```
( cd /longpath; mv longfile morepath/ )
```

while keeping your current working directory in the shell you are working in.

This isn't entirely dissimilar to [Wildcard's suggestion of using shell expansion](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/272984/2465) but can be done for more complex situations than a simple something-here-in-one-argument-only can readily support.

Comment: Worth noting that the spaces around the parentheses are for readability; they're not required (unlike using curly braces for command grouping where whitespace separation *is* required).