# Is there any way to execute commands from history?

Tags: bash, command-history

For example:

```
[root@ip-10-0-7-125 ~]# history | grep free
  594  free -m
  634  free -m | xargs | awk '{print "free/total memory" $17 " / " $ 8}'
  635  free -m
  636  free -m | xargs | awk '{print "free/total memory" $9 " / " $ 10}'
  736  df -h | xargs |  awk '{print "free/total disk: " $11 " / " $9}'
  740  df -h | xargs |  awk '{print "free/total disk: " $11 " / " $8}'
  741  free -m | xargs | awk '{print "free/total memory: " $17 " / " $8 " MB"}'
```

I'm just wondering if there any way to execute the 636 command without typing it again, just type something plus the number, like history 636 or something.

Comment: do you know about [`ctrl-r`](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/73498/how-to-cycle-through-reverse-i-search-in-bash)?

Comment: Yep, i know that but it's not exactly what i want.

Answer (score 345, accepted):

In bash, just `!636` will be ok.

Comment: `In Linux` - This has more to do with the shell (bash, zsh, etc) a person is running then the OS you are running it on.  There are shells on linux without support for history.

Comment: @Zoredache And similarly, this works fine in most implementations of bash on Windows.

Comment: Not just bash, of course, but other shells too - including csh.

Comment: If you've got a command that's very similar to what you want to run, you can append `:p` to print the command without running it, `!636:p` for example. Which means that you can easily select it again from your history by pressing the up arrow and make the minor changes you want

Comment: Very powerful stuff

Answer (score 100):

Yes, it's called "history expansion."  See

```
LESS='+/^HISTORY EXPANSION' man bash
```

for full details.

Using an exclamation point followed by a number is arguably the simplest use:

```
!636
```

However, you can also run the last executed command directly without knowing its history number:

```
!!
```

Or you can run two commands back:

```
!-2
```

The form I most often use, however, is to repeat the last argument of the last command:

```
echo this text goes into a file > /tmp/afile.txt
cat !$
```

Or, let's say I'm inspecting a file.  Using tab completion, I might do the following:

```
ls -l /really/long/path/to/some/file
less !$
```

Again, **read the man page** for more details:

```
LESS='+/^HISTORY EXPANSION' man bash
```

Comment: Interactively, `Alt-.` can be more convenient than `!$`. It inserts the last argument of the last command *verbatim* into the line.

Comment: @ulidtko Where are those special escapes documented (I knew about `!$`, but never heard about `Alt-.`)? Will you post a link to it, please?

Comment: `LESS="+/DEFAULT KEY BINDINGS" man 3 readline`, `/etc/inputrc`, `~/.inputrc`. Many programs besides bash use libreadline; for those who do, you get the same features like `Alt-.`, `Ctrl-X-U` (undo), `Ctrl-/` (describe shortcut), tab-completion, etc -- for free. For example, with just [three lines](http://stackoverflow.com/a/987402/531179) of `PYTHONSTARTUP` one can enable tab-completion and history in the *stock python REPL*. Which will work (mostly) the same as in bash, since it's the GNU Readline library that does the work. The readline's manpage describes the features in detail.

Comment: Also, Ctl-UpArrow (or AltUpArrow on bash) will scroll backwards through the history list.  Typing a few characters then the UpArrow gets only the commands starting with that letter, e.g. "fr(Ctl-Up)" scrolls through all the "free..." commands in the OP's list.  This also works in things like gnuplot & gdb that use readline.

Comment: @jamesqf:   It sounds like you're describing `history-search-backward`, but the bash man page doesn't list a default binding for it.  Did you have to configure that in `.inputrc`?  It does sound useful, though.  I knew about `M-.` (`yank-last-arg`) and `C-r` / `C-s`, and stuff like `M-C-e` (`shell-expand-line`)...  Either that or my terminal emulators are broken: In konsole and xterm (Ubuntu 15.10), I just get `A` characters from the end of the `^[[1;3A` escape sequence that alt+up generates.  Same for ctrl+up.

Comment: "the last argument of the last command" Hmm, but in the example you gave, `/tmp/afile.txt` wasn't the last argument, or even an argument at all. It was the target of output redirection. Does it just get the last token maybe?

Comment: @Ajedi32, see the final bolded line in my answer.  :)  Truthfully this answer is barely a taste of [what history expansion can do](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/272866/135943).  Keep in mind that this is at the level of the shell, not the command you are calling; hence `echo {1..5}` followed by `touch !$` will touch *five* files, not just one.  So strictly speaking it's not the last *argument* but the last shell word on that line.  (Also try `echo hello >temp` followed by `echo goodbye !$`.)  If you can think of a way to put it more clearly feel free to suggest an edit.

Comment: @Peter Cordes: You're right, I've had those bindings in place for so long (decades?) that I'd forgotten they weren't a default part of the system.  On my system (I use tcsh and xterm)  '"\e[415z": history-search-backward' is the line in .inputrc and .tcshrc. '421z' binds forward search to down arrow, others allow editing of the recovered line.  There's also the whole subject of completion rules, which I frankly don't really understand, but which should allow edited lines to be automagically expanded using only allowable values...

Answer (score 19):

A nice one, if you don't want to first history, note the number, etc:

in bash (and maybe others):

```
ctrl-r something
```

(`ctrl-r` = "reverse search interactively") (`something` = a part of a previous command)

This will show you the latest history line containing `something` . To get the one before, do ctrl-r (alone) again, each time it gets a previous line.

ex:

```
ctrl-r  10
```

to show the latest history line containing '10'  (for exemple the line with `$10`, in your exemple), and `ctrl-r` again until you retrieve the history line you were looking for

When the line you wanted appear, just `Enter` to run it (or you can also edit it, using the `arrow keys`, `backspace`, and `ctrl-a` to go to the beginning of the line, `ctrl-e` to get to the End,  `ctrl-k` : to "kill" from cursor to end of line (=deletes+saves it in a buffer),  `ctrl-y` : to restore, from the buffer, a previously killed bit, etc.)

If you want to  search forward (ctrl-s), **you first need to disable XON** : see https://stackoverflow.com/a/791800/1841533 :

" just to disable XON/XOFF by running

```
stty -ixon
```

"
(and then you will be able to use ctrl-s, without having it freeze the terminal)

Comment: If I do this and accidentally press ctrl-r one time too many, is there some way to search forward in the history again?

Comment: @kasperd: Yes you can. many answers on se points it out : ctrl-s for forward search.

Comment: Unfortunately ctrl-s is used to freeze the terminal, and bash doesn't disable that, so that doesn't work in the default configuration. (Other programs - such as emacs - disables the keybinding to freeze the terminal such that ctrl-s can be used for searching.)

Comment: @kasperd : Yes, sorry for not mentionning that earlier (I pointed "many answers" because they do precise that, but I didn't took the time to type this in the comment or give a link... (I was using my phone). I now came back home and could edit that in the answer above. ctrl-s for bash history search needs you to stty -ixon first

Comment: That command is going to break normal use of ctrl-s, so that's not really an option.

Comment: @kasperd: then just ctrl-c and start over (using a more specidic string if possible). For me, the stty is an option : I never needed to hang the terminal (was more useful în the typewriter days, I guess)

Comment: When I have accidentally pressed ctrl-r too many times, I do press ctrl-c and start over. In case of a long running command where I need to briefly freeze terminal output to inspect it or copy something from the output, ctrl-c is not an option. There is no guarantee that the command can be started over with the same result, and even if it could, I may have to wait hours for it to reach the same point.

Comment: you are mixing things: Ctrl-c in my last comment is for you to interrupt the ctrl-r and start the search again (with more precise string). About a long running cmd that you need to suspend a bit: you could freeze it with `ctrl-z` (=suspend), copy what you need, and `fg`(continue in foreground). Or use `Putty` or another and have it reset display on keypress only (not on new output, the default). or use `| tee somefile`, or `script thecommand`. And there are more ways (screen/tmux, etc). ctrl-s is not the only way to do it.

Answer (score 10):

You can use the shell builtin *fc*:

```
fc -s 636
```

Comment: This is actually *better* than the accepted answer, but you have to remove the `-s` to get the benefits.  If you run `fc 636` you will open an *editor* with command 636 from your history in the buffer, and when you save and exit the command (modified or not) will be run.  And even better, [this one is POSIX-compliant](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/fc.html).

Comment: @StevenPenny Thanks. And yes, I do know what POSIX is, though I don't see the relevance. Regardless, some easily accessed and included documentation would be nice.

Comment: @FaheemMitha try running "help fc."

Comment: @Wildcard `help` is not POSIX - might have to do `man dash` or similar

Comment: @Wildcard Thanks. I tend to forget `help` exists. Another shell builtin. And puzzling for unwary users who might want help with a new system, but instead are confronted with a stream of gibberish. :-(

Answer (score 7):

There is [`HSTR`](https://github.com/dvorka/hstr) - `hstr` command for `bash` and `zsh` interactive command selection, better than Ctrl-R reverse search:

[image: hstr interactive history command example]

It's interactive, so you can search for, and edit the command, before executing it.

On Ubuntu, you can install `hstr` with the following one-liner:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ultradvorka/ppa && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install hstr && hstr --show-configuration >> ~/.bashrc && . ~/.bashrc
```

or step by step:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ultradvorka/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install hstr
```

Install `hstr` on Fedora, RHEL or CentOS:

```
sudo dnf install hstr -y
```

On macOS with `homebrew`:

```
brew install hstr
```

...then configure it with:

```
hstr --show-configuration >> ~/.bashrc
```

This will replace the default Ctrl-R behavior.

Run `hstr --show-configuration` to determine what will be appended to your Bash profile.

More configuration options available on project homepage at Github:
https://github.com/dvorka/hstr

Comment: HSTR is great! 
Note: The package to install is `hstr` not `hh` The config to profile command sets an 'hh' alias.