# How to run one command with a directory as argument, then cd to the same? I get "no such file or directory"

Tags: bash, cd-command

I would like to construct a short function to do the following. Let's say that I move file 'file.tex' to my documents directory:

```
mv file.tex ~/Documents
```

Then, I'd like to `cd` to that directory:

```
cd ~/Documents
```

I'd like to generalize this to any directory, so that I can do this:

```
mv file.tex ~/Documents
follow
```

and have the `follow` command read the destination from the previous command, then execute accordingly. For a simple directory, this doesn't save much time, but when working with nested directories, it would be tremendous to be able to just use

```
mv file.tex ~/Documents/folder1/subfolder1
follow
```

I thought it would be relatively simple, and that I could do something like this:

```
follow()
{
    place=`history 2 | sed -n '1p;1q' | rev | cut -d ' ' -f1 | rev`
    cd $place
}
```

but this doesn't seem to work. If I echo `$place`, I do get the desired string (I'm testing it with `~/Documents`), but the last command returns

```
No such file or directory
```

The directory certainly exists. I'm at a loss. Could you help me out?

Comment: I'd like to point out that if you do not mind keeping `file.tex` in the original location, [symlinks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link) are a very good alternative, since you only have to link once, and then it will always point to the latest version.

Comment: Easier way: type `cd ` alt+`.` to substitute the last token of the previous command.  Repeat to go further back in the history of final tokens.  (I say token not arg, because `foo &` grabs `&` as the final token.)  You can use a numeric argument (with escape-3 alt+. for example).

Comment: Further reading: [Is there any way to execute commands from history?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/275061/135943) and also [What is a fast command line way to switch between multiple directories for system administration?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/286628/135943)

Comment: see also [mkdir cd combo](http://superuser.com/questions/1073869/how-can-i-make-my-own-shell-commands-e-g-mkdir-cd-combo)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Instead of defining a function, you can use the variable `$_`, which is expanded to the last argument of the previous command by `bash`. So use:

```
cd "$_"
```

after `mv` command.

You can use history expansion too:

```
cd !:$
```

If you must use a function:

```
follow () { cd "$_" ;}
```

---

```
$ follow () { cd "$_" ;}
$ mv foo.sh 'foo bar'
$ follow 
foo bar$
```

**N.B:** This answer is targeted to the exact command line arguments format you have used as we are dealing with positional parameters. For other formats e.g. `mv -t foo bar.txt`, you need to incorporate specific checkings beforehand, a wrapper would be appropriate then.

Comment: Your history expansion (cd !:$) works perfectly. Thank you.

However, the other (cd "$_") does not:

mv file.tex ~/Downloads/
cd "$_"

bash: cd: __bp_preexec_invoke_exec: No such file or directory


I will very gladly accept your answer as entirely correct, and thank you.

Comment: I have always typed (somewhat wastefully) either `cd !$` or `cd $(dirname !$)`. Didn't know about the `$_` variable!

Comment: Now what happens if I do `mv -t ~/Documents file.tex` instead of `mv file.tex ~/Documents`? Bottom line, I'm not sure this is solvable in the general case... a wrapper function around or that reimplements `mv` might be better...

Comment: @MichaelKjörling Won't work simply..this example is just to cover the case OP has, not the edge (or all) cases..

Comment: You don't need the colon; `!$` is equivalent to `!:$` and faster to type.

Comment: Note the difference between `!$` and `"$_"` when run after `mv file "dir$((++n))"` for instance.

Answer (score 14):

With standard bash keybindings, the combination <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>.</kbd> will copy the last argument of the previous command line into the current one. So, typing

```
$ mv foo ~/some/long/path/
$ cd <Alt><.>
```

would yield

```
$ mv foo ~/some/long/path/
$ cd ~/some/long/path/
```

and would be even less typing than the word `follow`.

For added convenience, repeating the <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>.</kbd> combination will browse through the last arguments of all previous command lines.

*Addendum:* The bash command name corresponding to this key combination is `yank-last-arg` or `insert-last-argument`. It can be found in the bash manpage under "Commands for Manipulating the History" or in the more exhaustive [Bash Reference Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Commands-For-History).)

Comment: That's clever. Thanks! I had no idea this existed.

Comment: @Fire I added references for those commands, so you can find a lot more interesting key bindings (and immediately forget them again, like I always do).

Comment: You can also use `<esc>` then `.` to get the same result as `<alt>+.`, this useful when you have remapped capslock to escape :)

Comment: @gnur vi(m) user, I suppose. ;-)

Answer (score 6):

You're almost certainly running into the problem that tilde expansion takes place before parameter expansion, which can be explained by a succinct example:

```
$ cd ~kaz
kaz $ var='~kaz'
kaz $ echo $var
~kaz
kaz $ cd $kaz
bash: cd: ~kaz: No such file or directory
```

This can be addressed with `eval`. Anyway, you're going to need `eval`, because you're pulling commands from the history and they can contain arbitrary expansions, like:

```
$ mv file.tex ~/Documents/$(compute_folder_name foo-param)/subfolder1
$ follow
```

(There are issues, such as that the re-expansion of these values might no longer match the original expansion which occurred. Suppose `compute_folder_name` is a function which increments some global variable.)

Comment: You don't need `eval`.  (Ever.)  But good spotting on the expansion sequence problems.  If you mention the greater advisability of history expansion to using `eval` here, this will be the best answer in my opinion; none of the others actually explain *why* the Original Poster's solution failed to work.