# How to cp in two steps

Tags: file-copy, clipboard

Every once in a while, I find the need to do:

```
cp /really/long/path/to/file.txt /totally/different/long/path/to/copy.txt
```

Since I use [`autojump`](https://github.com/wting/autojump), *getting* to the directories is very fast and easy. However, I'm at a loss when it comes to copying from one directory to the other without having to type out at least one of the full paths.

In a GUI filesystem navigator, this is easy: navigate to the first directory; **Copy** the original file; navigate to the second directory; and **Paste**. But with `cp`, it seems like I can't do the copy in two steps.

I'm looking to do something like the following:

```
(use autojump to navigate to the first directory)
$ copy file.txt
(use autojump to navigate to the second directory)
$ paste copy.txt
```

Instead of the longer-to-type:

```
(use autojump to navigate to the first directory)
$ cp file.txt /totally/different/long/path/to/copy.txt
```

Is there a tool that provides the functionality I'm looking for? I'm using Zsh on OS X El Capitan.

Comment: You might also like to try out [Alfred](https://www.alfredapp.com/powerpack/).  I use the powerpack features all the time.  Granted I don't use them at the terminal, though.

Comment: (autojump to first directory) `src="$PWD/file.txt"` (autojump to second directory) `cp "$src" copy.txt`

Comment: Really similar to http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/268824/117549

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The below works in `bash`.  I haven't tried it in `zsh`.

Try:

```
echo ~-   # Just to make sure you know what the "last directory" is
```

Then:

```
cp file.txt ~-/copy.txt
```

Also see:

- [More examples of use of `~-` (and its interaction with `pushd` and `popd`)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/286628/135943)
- [Is it possible to name a part of a command to reuse it in the same command later on?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/272858/135943)

Comment: This looks perfect! I can use `dirs -v` to check the stack, and then `~#` to reference the other path (where `#` is the integer identifying the directory on the stack). Also, I can confirm this works fine in `zsh`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative solution, inspired by the comment by @Stephen Harris:

```
# You can "copy" any number of files, then "paste", "move" or
# "pasteln" them to pass them as arguments to cp, mv, or ln
# respectively. Just like a graphical filesystem manager. Each of the
# latter three functions defaults to the current directory as the
# destination.
function copy() {
    emulate -LR zsh
    radian_clipboard=()
    for target; do
        radian_clipboard+=(${target:a})
    done
}
function paste() {
    emulate -LR zsh
    cp -R $radian_clipboard ${1:-.}
}
function move() {
    emulate -LR zsh
    mv $radian_clipboard ${1:-.}
}
function pasteln() {
    emulate -LR zsh
    ln -s $radian_clipboard ${1:-.}
}
```

Example usage:

```
(autojump to first directory)
$ copy file.txt
(autojump to second directory)
$ paste copy.txt
```

As you can see, these aliases are very thin wrappers around the `cp`, `mv`, and `ln -s` commands, so you can also pass a directory as the second argument, or `copy` multiple files or directories at once, or omit the second argument to act on the current directory.

Comment: `paste` is already [a POSIX-specified tool](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/paste.html), but I like this idea.  You could improve it further by checking the number of arguments to `copy` and the number of arguments to `paste` and defaulting to `./` if no argument given to `paste`.  You could even use `bash` arrays to allow multiple files to be copied, at which point `paste` would not accept any arguments but would just run `cp -i "${copy_paths[@]}" .` (or do nothing if `copy_paths` is empty).